# Scrapy not scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape news off a website, but the spider that I have created is not scraping anything when it crawl and I receive this in the log: **INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)**.

Below is my code:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AoscraperItem

items = AoscraperItem()


class AoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ao_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://mothership.sg/", callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        article_links = response.xpath("//div[@class='ind-article']/a/@href")
        article_links_ext = article_links.extract()

        for url in article_links_ext:
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_article)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//h1/text()").get()
        # author_date = response.xpath("//div[@class='article-info ao-link-news']/span")
        author = response.xpath("//span[@class='author-name']/text()").get()
        date = response.xpath("//span[@class='publish-date']/text()").get()

        items["title"] = title
        items["author"] = author
        items["date"] = date

        yield items
```

I am unable to figure out why it does not scrape anything on the website.

Really appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `XPath` is incorrect while extracting links in `parse` function. It should be `article_links = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ind-article')]/a/@href")` or you can use below modified code.

**Code**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AoscraperItem

items = AoscraperItem()


class AoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ao_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://mothership.sg/", callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        article_links = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ind-article')]/a/@href")
        article_links_ext = article_links.extract()

        for url in article_links_ext:
                yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_article,dont_filter=True)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//h1/text()").get()
        # author_date = response.xpath("//div[@class='article-info ao-link-news']/span")
        author = response.xpath("//span[@class='author-name']/text()").get()
        date = response.xpath("//span[@class='publish-date']/text()").get()


        items["title"] = title
        items["author"] = author
        items["date"] = date

        yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, it will work fine.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AoscraperItem

items = AoscraperItem()


class AoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ao_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://mothership.sg/", callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        article_links = response.xpath('//*[@id="latest-news"]/div/a/@href')
        article_links_ext = article_links.extract()

        for url in article_links_ext:
                yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_article,dont_filter=True)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//h1/text()").get()
        # author_date = response.xpath("//div[@class='article-info ao-link-news']/span")
        author = response.xpath("//span[@class='author-name']/text()").get()
        date = response.xpath('(//*[@class="publish-date"]/text())[2]').get()


        items["title"] = title
        items["author"] = author
        items["date"] = date

        yield items
```